# C# Word VSTO addin - Drag and drop from treeView to word document

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-word, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am building a word addin using visual studio (c#)

Can someone help to implement the drag and drop event from a TreeView node in a user control to the body of the word document and in the chosen position by the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You need to narrow the focus of your question, and you need to show that you have made some effort to solve the issue on your own (provide a code sample). SO is not meant produce entire programming solutions for you.

Comment: Hi @Connor, thanks for the advice. Please note that I already answered my own question. Please check below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

Let me share it with you.

If you need to drag and drop an item from a Treeview control to a word document you need to implement two event handlers: **MouseDown** and **MouseMove**

```
 private bool MouseIsDown;
 private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseIsDown = true;

        TreeView tree = (TreeView)sender;

        TreeNode node = tree.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        tree.SelectedNode = node;
    }

    private void treeView1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseIsDown)
        {
            this.treeView1.DoDragDrop(this.treeView1.SelectedNode.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
        MouseIsDown = false;
    }
```

Please note that this is different than implementing the drag and drop within the TreeView itself.